# Assertion failed in selenium web testing

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I try to execute a new unit test case it displays the below error.

Note: I do not have privilege to set the path due to the I have placed the chrome web driver in D drive.

> Testing started at 14:56 ...
>       C:\Users\xxx.xxxx\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   "C:\Users\xx.xxx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
>   2019.2\helpers\pycharm_jb_unittest_runner.py" --path C:/Users/xx.xxx/PycharmProjects/Automation/UnitTest_1.py
>       Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest C:/Users/xx.xx/PycharmProjects/Automation/UnitTest_1.py in
>   C:\Users\xx.xxx\PycharmProjects\Automation
>
> Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\xxxx\xxxxx\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\lib\site-
>
> packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 76, in start
>           stdin=PIPE)
>         File "C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
>           restore_signals, start_new_session)
>         File "C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
>           startupinfo)
>       FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

When I handled the above exception, I got an another exception a
below.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in
>   testPartExecutor
>       yield   File "C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 615, in
>   run
>       testMethod()   File "C:\xxxx\xxxxx\PycharmProjects\Automation\UnitTest_1.py", line 17, in
>   test_Bing
>       self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\test\chromedriver.exe")   File
>   "C:\xxxx\xxxx\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
>   line 73, in **init**
>       self.service.start()   File "C:\xxxx\xxxxx\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
>   line 83, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
>   'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see
>
> https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
>
> Ran 2 tests in 2.374s
>
> FAILED (errors=2)
>   Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in
>   testPartExecutor
>       yield   File "C:\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 615, in
>   run
>       testMethod()   File "C:\Users\xxx.xxxx\PycharmProjects\Automation\UnitTest_1.py", line 10,
>   in test_Google
>       self.driver.get("www.google.com")   File "C:\Users\xx.xxxx\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 333, in get
>       self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})   File "C:\Users\xx.xxxx\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\xx.xxxxx\PycharmProjects\Automation\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
>   argument   (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)
>
> Assertion failed
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
>
> Assertion failed
>
> Assertion failed

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep +r"D:\test\chromedriver.exe"
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class SearchEnginesTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Google(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\test\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("www.google.com")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        # self.driver.save_screenshot("D:\\test\\one.jpg")
        print("Title of the page :  " + self.driver.title)
        self.driver.close()

    def test_Bing(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\test\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("www.bing.com")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        # self.driver.save_screenshot("D:\\test\\two.jpg")
        print("Title of the page:    " + self.driver.title)
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that all paths in your code are accessable to the os sys.path in python.
Also, check that the *.py scripts are in directories listed in the python path list file 'python._pth'.
Check your operating system instructions on updates to path, in most 'locked down' computers you can still edit the 'user path'.
Another option is to create a 'runner' script - an os script of *.bat on windows or *.sh for shell.
In the runner script set/add the os sys.path and add files to python path dynamically and when the script finishes
the 'adds' will disappear back to lockdown only path. Submit ITIL ticket about your script to get approved by sys admins too.